# How to match independent arrays to convert them into array of objects

Tags: arrays, json, apache-nifi, associative-array, jolt

don't know how to use jolt's transformations such as **shift**、**default**、**modify-default-beta**.

I have the following array value as

**input** :

```json
{
  "a": [
    [
      "1",
      "2",
      "3"
    ],
    [
      "11",
      "22",
      "33"
    ]
  ],
  "b": [
    "age",
    "name",
    "address"
  ]
}
```

**expected output** :

```json
[
  {
    "age": "1",
    "name": "2",
    "address": "3"
  },
  {
    "age": "11",
    "name": "22",
    "address": "33"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following **shift** transformation spec

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "a": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "@": "[&2].@(4,b[&1])"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

where we walk through the subindexes of the array sorted by

- a[0][0]
- a[0][1]
- a[0][2]
- a[1][0]
- a[1][1]
- a[1][2]

and step by step match

- b[0]
- b[1]
- b[2]
- as getting the value of the array **b** after traversing **4** levels
  up the tree

  (once per ***`:`***, triple per ***`{`***)
- while tiling them arraywise by **`[&2]`**